# Accidentally removed JupyterLab from anaconda navigator

Tags: anaconda, jupyterlab

Was fiddling with navigator, and clicked "Remove Application" on JupyterLab. It's clearly still installed, I can see it in the list of packages in the environment. But is there a way to make it show up on the Navigator home page again?